# SQL Server 2012 AFTER INSERT trigger that replaces null value with current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-insert

I need to create a trigger that inserts the current date for the `DateAdded` column of the `Products` table if the value for that column is `null`.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Use MyGuitarShop;
IF OBJECT_ID ('Products_INSERT') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TRIGGER Products_INSERT;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER Products_INSERT
    ON Products
    AFTER INSERT
AS
    UPDATE Products
    SET DateAdded = GETDATE()
    WHERE DateAdded IS NULL
        AND DateAdded IN (SELECT DateAdded FROM inserted);
GO
```

To test this I ran the following `INSERT` statement:

```
INSERT INTO Products
VALUES (4, 'AK-5300', 'Awesome Keyboard 5300',
        'This keyboard is so awesome, you just might freak!',
        699.99, 30.00, NULL)
```

After running the `INSERT` statement, the `DateAdded` column still says `NULL`.

Any help is appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using a trigger for this?  Just give the column a default value of `getdate()`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's part of my assignment, the trigger is meant to update any records that may be inserted in the future without a specified date, such that it would include the current date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach isn't the right approach.  You should just use a default value for `DateAdded`.  But, the problem with this query:

```
UPDATE Products
SET DateAdded = GETDATE()
WHERE DateAdded IS NULL
    AND DateAdded IN (SELECT DateAdded FROM inserted);
```

Is that the two conditions are incompatible.  You have `DataAdded IS NULL` fine.  That is true.  But almost any comparison to `NULL` is false, including the `IN` comparison.  So for what you want to do, this should suffice:

```
UPDATE Products
SET DateAdded = GETDATE()
WHERE DateAdded IS NULL;
```

You could write:

```
UPDATE Products
SET DateAdded = GETDATE()
WHERE DateAdded IS NULL OR
      DateAdded IN (SELECT DateAdded FROM inserted);
```

I do note that the trigger is updating the same table being modified, which often leads to confusing code.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon! I think I was over-complicating the question. Thanks a lot!